# Checkered face on cube

Tags: mesh, 3d-view

On cubes, one of the faces has a checkered face, that doesn't like to cooperate with what I am doing. Can someone shed some light on what exactly this face is, and what it's purpose is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basic ingredients of a mesh are triangles (*tris*), [quadrilaterals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilateral) (*quads*), and polygons with n sides (n > 4, *n-gons*). N-gon is the least often used, and indeed Blender's own support for true n-gon is fairly recent (2.63).

The lower right face of your problematic mesh is a **[concave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_polygon) quad**. Normally, proper rendering of a concave polygon requires it to be decomposed/fragmented into several convex polygons, a doable operation but [potentially expensive [PDF]](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~chazelle/pubs/OptimalConvexDecomp.pdf) for realtime display. Blender doesn't do such operation, blindly drawing a face for each connected edges in each [polygons](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_2/bpy.types.Mesh.html#bpy.types.Mesh.polygons) in a mesh, hence the "ghost face".

To avoid such occurence, manually convert the quad to tris (select the face, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>) for the upper and lower part of the quad:

[image: 1]

Comment: Can you explain in your example why there are checkers on the bottom left?

Comment: If selected, the active face is also checkered, to differentiate it from other selected faces being highlighted.